# Attaching an object to the side of a centered div

Tags: html, css

I want a centered column of content with the logo attached to the outside of its top left hand corner, as in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et4j38w2/1/).

HTML:

```
<div>
    I'm centered
    <div>
        I'm glued to the centered div
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
div div
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  left: -100px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I'm not satisfied with my own solution because it seems like a failure of separation of content and presentation  - in my case the cyan box is a logo and the pink box is the content. I can't create a wrapper div for both content and logo, since it's the content I want centered, not the content and logo together.

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DIV next to centered div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433848/div-next-to-centered-div)

Comment: @NilsSchlüter The accepted answer there is quite good and does indeed answer the question as I wrote it, but in my case I actually have two things that need to be centered in a single column (the content, and a navbar above it). I could put them in a wrapper, but that's more non-semantic markup.

Comment: I don't understand why you're not satisfied with your own solution, it looks good to me.

Comment: @AminJafari Maybe I [worry too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965892/is-a-wrapper-div-a-violation-of-content-style-separation).

Comment: I agree with the selected answer. It may be a violation, but it doesn't actually matter. Take it easy my friend :)